# Check if words of a string is present in a string list

Tags: c#, string, linq, list, contains

I have the following code that works a treat -

```
List<string> test = new List<string>();
test.Add("cat");

if (test.Any(str => str.Contains("cat")))
{
      // do something
};
```

However is there a way to check if there is not an exact match for instance -

```
if (test.Any(str => str.Contains("the cat sat")))
{
      // do something
};
```

I want to be able to check if **any** of the words in the string are present in the list. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Additional Hint: If you are only testing for `Contains`, use a `HashSet<>` instead of a `List<>` - it's a lot faster when you have a lot of data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should extract words and check for existence of them in elements of `test`

```
var data = "the cat sat";
var words = data.Split(null);
if (test.Any(str => words.Any(word => str.Contains(word)))
{
  // do something
}
```

If you want to check for exact match you should use `word => str == word`.

```
"a cat".Contains("cat") //true
"a cat" == "cat" //false
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply do by this way

```
string check = "the cat sat";
if(test.Any(str => check.Split(' ').Contains(str)))
{
      // present
};
```

Answer (score 4):

`Split` your sentence into the different words:

```
var words = new HashSet<string>("the cat sat".Split(' '));
```

And then you can:

1. Check if that collection contains any of the `str`s:

   ```
   var test = new List<string> { "cat" };
   var words = new HashSet<string>("the cat sat".Split(' '));

   var result =  test.Any(str => words.Contains(str)); // In this case "true"
   ```
2. Use `Intersect`:

   ```
   var test = new List<string> { "cat" };
   var words = new HashSet<string>("the cat sat".Split(' '));

   var result = test.Intersect(words).Any();
   ```

*The use of the `HashSet` is so when you go through the 2 collections it'll in `o(n)` and not `o(n)2`*

If you do not have exact matches in the `test` list like in the following example:

```
var test = new List<string> { "some cat" };
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
var test = new List<string> { "some cat" };
var words = "the cat sat".Split(' ').ToList();

var result = words.Any(word => test.Any(item => item.Contains(word)));
```

Answer (score 2):

One way of achieving this would be to make use of an extension to the `string` object.

```
public static bool Contains(this string input, bool caseSensitive, params string[] items)
{
    input = !caseSensitive ? input.ToLower() : input;

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        if (input.Contains(!caseSensitive ? item.ToLower() : item))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Your following line would then also work with a minor change:

```
if (test.Any(str => str.Contains(true, "the", "cat", "sat"))) // true for case sensitive contains
{
      // do something
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bool contains = false;        
string checkString = "the cat sat";
checkString.Split(' ').ToList().Foreach(x => {
  if (test.Any(str => str.Contains(x)) && !contains)
  {
      // do something
      contains = true;
  };
});
```